# how to make a dynamic query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am working on a little searching stuffs, the problem is that I they can choose multiple options and I want my query to be created depending of them.

Please if anybody could help me I will be so glad.

My main table of search is this:

```
id
name
card_id
phone_numbre
country_id
futurecountry_id
```

The ID is unique, the name a text, the card_id and  phone_number are just ok, I can find them on my table, but the problem is when I need to go to pick up the data to the other tables, specially the country_id goes to a table named "country" where I comprare the id's to check if are the same I bring the name of the country, is the same table where I consult for get the country_id and futurecountry_id and I really have no idea what to do.

Does anybody have any idea?

p.s. Well, maybe I couldn't explain myself very good, my problem is this:

I have a form where you filled it with some data and brings you the personal information and instead the ids of the field origencountry and destinycountry I need the names, for example, if I send origencountry=10 and destinycountry=8 I will do this:

```
select * 
from infotable,countrytable 
where infotable.iddestinycountry = countrytable.id and infotable = 10 
AND infotable.origencountry = countrytable.id  and infotable = 8
```

The query seems to work fine, but it doesn't output any data.
At my table countries I have for example:

```
id name

1  usa

2  uk

3  spain
```

---

and at info

```
id name origencountry destinycountry

1  john      1             2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN.

For example :

```
SELECT c.country_id from country as c
LEFT JOIN futurecountry as fc ON c.country_id = fc.futurecountry_id
```

In this example, you return only results on country with country and futurecountry_id keys

For more informations, you can see here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/join.html